# How can I create a matrix in a void function and return as parameter C

Tags: c, multidimensional-array, pass-by-reference, function-definition, function-declaration

I have to create a matrix but with the following requirements:

- create a function for it
- the matrix has to be dynamic allocated inside the function
- the matrix has to be returned as a parameter of the function (function has to be void)

What I tried:

```
void createMatrix(int n,float** matrix)
{

    matrix = (float**)malloc(n * sizeof(float*));
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        matrix[i] = (float*)malloc(n* sizeof(float));
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
            matrix[i][j] = 0;
}
int main()
{
    int n;
    FILE* fis;
    fis = fopen("fileIn.txt", "r");
    if (!fis)
    {
        printf("File not opened");
        return;
    }
    fscanf(fis, "%d", &n);
    fclose(fis);
    float** matrix;
    createMatrix(n, &matrix);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
            printf("%f ", matrix[i][j]);
        printf("\n");
    }
    return;
}
```

Comment: You should enable compiler warnings and fix all warnings.

Answer (score 1):

If you're passing the address of a `float **` to a function, the type of the parameter should be `float ***`.  So in the function, change the parameter type to that and use `*matrix` wherever `matrix` was used.

```
void createMatrix(int n, float ***matrix)
{

    *matrix = malloc(n * sizeof(float*));
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        (*matrix)[i] = malloc(n* sizeof(float));
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
            (*matrix)[i][j] = 0;
}
```

Note that the casts have also been removed, as casting the return value of `malloc` is not necessary and can mask other errors in your code.

You also should add error checking after the calls to `malloc`.

Comment: Why would someone ever want to allocate a square 2D matrix like this?

Comment: @Lundin It's not the most efficient in terms of memory, but it directly addresses OP's issues.

Comment: But if there doesn't exist a single technical/practical reason for doing it like this, why would anyone want to do it? The OP is likely a beginner, we should teach them how to allocate arrays correctly.

Answer (score 1):

If you are creating the matrix such a way

```
matrix = (float**)malloc(n * sizeof(float*));
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    matrix[i] = (float*)malloc(n* sizeof(float));
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
        matrix[i][j] = 0;
```

and want to return the matrix through a parameter then the function should be declared like

```
void createMatrix( int n, float ***matrix )
{
    *matrix = malloc( n * sizeof( float* ) );

    for ( int i = 0; i < n; i++ )
        ( *matrix )[i] = malloc( n * sizeof( float ) );

    for ( int i = 0; i < n; i++ )
    {
        for ( int j = 0; j < n; j++ )
        {
            ( *matrix )[i][j] = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

That is if you are passing the pointer `matrix` declared in main like

```
float** matrix;
```

to the function by reference through a pointer to it

```
createMatrix(n, &matrix);
```

then the corresponding function parameter will have the type `float ***`.

Comment: Why would someone ever want to allocate a square 2D matrix like this?

Comment: @Lundin Firstly not all compilers support variable length arrays. And secondly of course it is much better when the result pointer is returned from the function.

Comment: You don't need to use VLA to do something like `float (*fmat)[42] = calloc( 1, sizeof(float[42][42]) );`. Either way, it's best to upgrade to a standard C compiler with VLA support.

Answer (score 1):

Some things to note:

- Your function is creating a pointer-to-pointer look-up table, not a 2D array. Pointer-to-pointer look-up tables only make sense when we want individually-sized items, which is never the case in a mathematical, square-shaped matrix. All the pointer-to-pointer trick achieves is bloat, slow access and needless complexity. You gain absolutely no advantages from it. For details see [Correctly allocating multi-dimensional arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42094465/correctly-allocating-multi-dimensional-arrays)
- This look-up table is assigned to the *local* variable `matrix` and not returned from the function, which is a bug and a memory leak.

We can easily fix these bugs and design mistakes if you can drop those requirements you listed. Then there's a much better standard C function for all of this called `calloc`.

Usage:

```
size_t fx = 5;
size_t fy = 3;
float (*fmat)[fy] = calloc( 1, sizeof(float[fx][fy]) );
...
free(fmat);
```

This is *much* faster than your function, it doesn't come with needless type-generic programming, it allocates a true 2D array in contiguous memory which gives data cache coherence and it sets all data items to zero.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to change `createMatrix` as follows:

```
void createMatrix(int n,float*** matrix)
{
    *matrix = (float**)calloc(n,sizeof(float*));
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        *matrix[i] = (float*)calloc(n,sizeof(float));
}
```

In order for the caller to be able to see the matrix you create, you have to pass a pointer to it... yes, that is a pointer-to-a-pointer-to-a-pointer. And by using `calloc` instead of `malloc`, the initialization to zero is handled for you.

Comment: Why would someone ever want to allocate a square 2D matrix like this?